# Jquery - add attr selected, but value remains 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have about 5 selects in my HTML code and I have this Jquery code, which compare the text of the options in every select with the text from an array.

The code works. Every select has the right option, but when I send the form the val of select is 0 and it should be for example 6

```js
$(function() {
  var index = 0;
  var navHrefNames = ['index', 'index', '', '', 'index'];
  $("select").each(function() {
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == navHrefNames[index]) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
    });
    index++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>
```

How can I set the value of option to the right value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting selected values on a form element, you should use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), rather than [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc) for why this distinction matters.

Relevant quote from the docs (emphasis mine):

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the `checked`
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the `checked` property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the `defaultChecked` property and
>   should be used only to set the *initial* value of the checkbox. The
>   `checked` attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the `checked` property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property:
>
> - `if ( elem.checked )`
> - `if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )`
> - `if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )`
>
> **The same is true for other dynamic attributes, such as `selected` and
>   `value`**.

As an aside, your element IDs should always be unique. This is a requirement of the HTML spec, and your jQuery code will behave in unexpected ways when those IDs aren't unique.

```js
$(function() {
  var index = 0;
  var navHrefNames = ['index', 'index', '', '', 'index'];
  $("select").each(function() {
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == navHrefNames[index]) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    });
    index++;
  });

  $("select").each(function() {
    $("body").append("<div>" + this.id + ' - ' + $(this).val() + "</div>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select0" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select1" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select2" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select3" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select4" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) in your `if` condition, below is the updated code:

```js
$(function() {
  var index = 0;
  var navHrefNames = ['index', 'index', '', '', 'index'];
  $("select").each(function() {
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
      if ($.inArray($(this).text(), navHrefNames)) {
        console.log('Something matched...');
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      } else {
        console.log("Not matching anything in array");
      }
    });
    index++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>

<select id="select" name="pages"><option value="">Vyberte stránku</option><option value="6">index</option></select>
```